# ¿Cómo añadir una imagen del sistema de archivos a un request.Files en Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

Se desea añadir en una vista en Django una imagen a un request.Files, he intentado el siguiente código pero obtengo el siguiente error a la hora de válidar el forms. "No se ha enviado ningún fichero. Compruebe el tipo de codificación en el formulario."

```
with open('imagen.jpeg', 'rb') as f:
    request.FILES['imagen'] = f

formulario = ProductoForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.save()
    else:
        data["form"] = formulario
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu HTML en los atributos de la etiqueta form debe ir en enctype del tipo apropiado:

```
<form action="{% 'url' tu_url " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```